# Javascript Regex, match beginning of the sentence, the end and discard the rest?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to extract multiple sentences that begins with `#` and ends with `.nr` exactly.

In this example only 2 sentences meets my requirements.

```
<textarea id="input" style="width:100%;height:350px;">

name: John Smith
tel. 02222222222.nr   <!-- discard --->

#name: Maria White
tel. 03333333333      <!-- discard --->

#name: Bryan Red
tel. 04444444444.nr   <!-- My Requirements: MATCH --->

#name: Sarah Brown
tel.                  <!-- discard --->

#name: George White
tel. 01111111111      <!-- discard --->

name:
tel. 03333333333.nr   <!-- discard --->

#name: Kelly Preston
tel. 03333333333.nr   <!-- My Requirements: MATCH --->

</textarea>

<p id="output"></p>

<script language="javascript">
var str = document.getElementById("input").value;
var output = str.match(/[#][^\.]*[.nr]+/g);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [`^#.*\n.*\.nr$`](https://regex101.com/r/1JneSY/1)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following regex :

```
/^#.*\n.*\.nr$/gm
```

See it in action on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/09FQd1/5).

It matches a `#` at the start on the line, then any character but a linefeed, then a linefeed, then any character up to and including an `.nr` at the end of the line. It relies on the `g`lobal flag to match multiple results from your string, and the `m`ultiline flag so that `^` and `$` match respectively the start and the end of every line rather than the start and the end of the string.

Comment: Use `^#.*\n.*\.nr$`. Aaron's regex will accept `fdjksla;fjds#something abcdnr`. Note that it should match string ending with `.nr`

Comment: @Avel I've updated the regex so that `#` must be at the start of a line and `.nr` at the end of the following.

Answer (score 1):

`/#.*\n.*\.nr/g`:

```
    #    : literal '#'
    .*   : a sequence of one or more characters (by default \n is not allowed)
    \n   : a new line
    .*   : ...
    \.nr : literal ".nr"
```

```js
var text = document.getElementById("input").value;

var matches = text.match(/#.*\n.*\.nr/g);

console.log(matches);
```

```html
<textarea id="input" style="width:100%;height:350px;">
name: John Smith
tel. 02222222222.nr  

#name: Maria White
tel. 03333333333      

#name: Bryan Red
tel. 04444444444.nr   

#name: Sarah Brown
tel.                  

#name: George White
tel. 01111111111     

name:
tel. 03333333333.nr

#name: Kelly Preston
tel. 03333333333.nr
</textarea>
```